# How do I use SKLearn KMeans on all the partitions of a partitioned dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, k-means

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: [city (String), weather_variable (String), variable_value (Float)].
I want to apply kmeans on the dataset after partitioning the data on city and weather_variable. i.e., the kmeans will run on all the combination of city, weather_variable separately. I have written a code for the same but it is very slow. Can someone help me optimize it?

**Code:**

```
i=0
x = None
grouped = test.groupby(['city', 'weather_variable'])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 7)

for name, frame in grouped: #I want to avoid this for loop
    kmeans.fit(frame.variable_value.reshape(-1, 1))
    frame['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
    if i == 0:
        x = frame
    else:
        x = x.append(frame)        
    i += 1
```

PS: I can't share the data here.

Comment: Hi there, the reason it is slow is because you are running a fit method for huge numbers of datasets that don't appear to be scaled. Out of curiosity why are you pre-slicing a data set then using a cluster algorithm?  Why not use the elbow method and cluster the entire dataset?

Comment: @Tiblit I'm pre-slicing the data because I want to apply k-means at city-weather_variable level level .Moreover, I'm not aware of the use of elbow method. I know that it is used to find the optimum number of clusters. But in my case the number of clusters has to be 7. If there's a way to do this without pre-slicing the data, I would like to try that. I would appreciate if you can help me out with it. TIA